# Using onselect attribute in <input type='file'>

Tags: javascript, android, html, input-type-file

I want the Android camcorder on mobile devices to start when the  button is clicked. After the video is recorded, I want reflect() to be initiated. My problem is that the function is not completed, and I think (but not 100% sure) this happens because I am using type='file' instead of a different type.

I've tried adding an event handler, which also didn't work. Any idea how I can get this a function to perform after clicking on the input button?

```
<form>
    <input type="file" accept="video/*;capture=camcorder" class="custom-file-input" onselect="reflect()" />
</form>

<script>
var reflect = function(){
    console.log('the reflect function is working.')
}
</script>
```

Comment: use `onchange` on file inputs

Comment: onslect fires when text is selected in an input.... is that what you are really wanting

Comment: Well no since file is the input. How can this input fire a function after clicking?

Comment: @dandavis, sorry. I saw the other comment but not yours until just now. onchange does work. Thank you! :)

Comment: ahh, the `@someone` makes it clear indeed, sorry. glad to help.

Comment: @rayon this is not a duplicate. I didn't notice the difference between `onclick` vs. `onchange`. The other one you suggested was an exact duplicate was a bit different.